# Full calendar extend cells

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

these days I am using full calendar and I am trying to add multiple events in one cell, but when I add more than one, it shows just +2 , I want to remove that and instead of the +2 it should extend the cell , in the photo you can see how it looks like for the moment[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVQVc.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is controlled by what you specify in the "eventLimit" option:

```
eventLimit: false
```

will stop it putting the +1, +2 etc type of text onto the calendar. If you want to move the limit to a higher number of events, to stop your calendar being too crowded on odd days where there is an unusual number, you can set it something like:

```
eventLimit: 10
```

however you please.

See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/eventLimit - there are other ways to use this option too - you can read all of this kind of thing for yourself in the fullCalendar documentation.